# How to test the effects of viewport meta tag?

Tags: html, accessibility, viewport, meta-tags

I am in the process of improving the accessibility of a web app, and one of the critical issues I have identified is [the presence of `user-scalable=no` and `maximum-scale=1.0`](https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/3.5/meta-viewport?application=axeAPI) in this tag:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
```

I understand why these attributes are an accessibility concern, and would like to remove them, but would like to test the "before and after" effects of the attributes and the lack of these attributes. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to test. My understanding is that the presence of these attributes will prevent a user from e.g., zooming the page, enlarging fonts, etc. However, in the app in question, they don't appear to have any effect on these things: I am able to zoom, enlarge fonts, etc. on both mobile and desktop in Chrome and Safari.

How can I go about testing the affects of `user-scalable=no` and `maximum-scale=1.0` so that I can resolve any issues that removing the attributes might create?

Comment: you can **pinch to zoom** with `user-scalable=no` and `maximum-scale=1.0`? That is the main thing it affects and if you can that would be surprising and possibly handled within your web app in some other way? Also depends on browser as some of them have started ignoring the attribute due to accessibility issues.

Comment: Yes, that am able to pinch zoom on Chrome and Safari in most recent version of iOS

Comment: @GrahamRitchie the app also uses `<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">`. Could this be overriding the viewport settings?

Comment: I would be surprised as that is an obsolete tag, I think only BlackBerrys recognise it now (maybe opera browser). Do you have a link to the page you can share. To answer the actual question removing it should have little to no effect unless you need to override pinch to zoom etc for functionality on the page. It is **meant** to stop you zooming.